# Typescript Type Guard wont affect the variable type if set indirectly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

TL;DR Difference between [link1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBZJcWD1RqgByCCrQaC0Ngber6AA8OAAfAAKeDSABW+TEnDw-AILIKoB58UghlSOAAlABtAC6iuF-IFImEOFAAG9FCUSk5UPivBL4ARBAFIHoyHgeTzLQRFaAALxcpKCgJ0gDyEk4zKt31QjpdisVigAvsEMgoyMkGEt4hluABGA1G+Ys0N4CrCzjsRDSb4Abhjce23yTKbTACYsyUXXmAEKF4ulsgV2PFdw0RCCZjCsx4D1ZlTN3NkMMF0Dp3jFaMVxQITiCGjcSCIDDu6WD4civBuz1NtHr9KCADSacze7pDKZ07ZgnZqZ46d5B-4yoARC2Z3zX91QrEo1w3HUbx4Rt7wYelGWDVkKA5d9uHrL8hx-f9nzwVtgMVFcShUABhbBYESA8cxDGdkN+EoEWlIQoIzN1DWNc9BHgdwAmgeBmB5X9mPTX8COzIiwCY29x1QMh2CUEpo3BaBBBQBieUk6DWLEjiuMgHi+IE5j6xE0DjRUDS0Ok2T5NARSYBUs8SiyeAJFAAADDIdAYaAKFcQAZcjc0zYzAxpOO43j+N-UjIHI+Y4JU1xAFByEzgno1J1OvW8tPY8DdP0-iDwCADZ1EhTszUiz62y41cvCgzCuK3DStsmMVxUHBmg8MgvB3PoGGBdgaC+NwzGYdgGGYSB+FgHzYv6+A9BELxfwAUVWBhEAWfRfySbFf3ABxUAAcmEAA5SAJF-IIVD9L4yHeFT+Emo5UEcBRXGkMcnB3HRhiwfQUAQRBoWES5hokeAyGiHVQEMfF5kYFg2C4bggiAA) (Working) vs [link2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBZJcWD1RqgByCCrQaC0Ngber6AA8OAAfAAKeDSABW%20TEnDw-AILIKoB58UghlSOAAlABtAC6iuF-IFImEOFAAG9FCUSk5UPivBL4ARBAFIHoyHgeTzLQRFaAALxcpKCgJ0gDyEk4zKt31QjpdisVigAvsEMgoyMkGEt4hluABGA1G40u0N4CrCzjsRDSb4xuPbb5JlNpgBMWeN8xZeYAQoXi6WyOXFO4aIhBMxhWY8B6Gznm2QwwXQOnu72dQBpNOZ904hjQQRKedCJc8eurpMbpTFADC2FgiX7I1zk4o%20kUCOl2ZKdIZTInbME7NTPHTvKv-DKs%20jagAARDeU6gbwwHqoobqGo2CCcII8DuAE0DwMwPKgbuGagVGjY7suo6oGQ7BKNG4JHiIqQ8sBr6MsGrJ3l%20P7cLW-4DoBwGNuBH54C2UEwVG8HAUhKFoRhWE4XW%20HAURe7uqR5ExlRm5jiUWTwBIoAAAYZDo64UK4gAy5Lp5biahkDoZh2FnpAF7zAwgibq4gCg5HJD60QpGaiYhjQSdZUk8leAQQfmUaxo%20PI%20bWfnGpZkm2aF4UtpFwQqDgzQeGQXiIPAfQMMC7A0F8bhmMw7AMMwkD8LA0DqIkRXwHoIheKBACiqwMIgCz6KBSTYqB4AOKgADkwgAHKQBIoFBCofpfGQ7ybvwNVHKgjgKK40gjk4%20U6MMWD6CgCCINCwiXGVEgFdEOqgIY%20LzIwLBsFw3BBEAA) (not working)

TypeGuard

```js
function hasAllProperties<T>(obj: any, props: (keyof T)[]): obj is T {
    return props.every((prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
}
```

Assume a variable `msg` that can be of 2 types - `kind1` or `kind2`.

```js
interface kind1 {
    propertyA: number
}

interface kind2 {
    propertyB: number
}

let msg: any = {
    propertyA: 1
}
```

In link1 the type guard is accessed directly and is working expected.
In link2 a boolean variable `isKind1` is initially set to false and only set to true if the type guard check is passed.

```js
let isKind1 = false
let isKind2 = false

// Check msg properties
if (
    hasAllProperties<kind1>(msg, [
        "propertyA",
    ])
) {
    console.log("Kind1")
    isKind1 = true
} else if (
    hasAllProperties<kind2>(msg, [
        "propertyB",
    ])
) {
    console.log("Kind2")
    isKind2=true
} else {
    throw `invalid ❌`
}
console.log("Check passed ✅")
```

Thus in link2 , I cannot think of a condition where if `isKind1 === true` but `msg` is **not** of type `kind1`

```js
if (isKind1) {
    // Why is msg not of only type kind1
    console.log(msg.propertyA)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of many situations where your code is correct, but Typescript just doesn't have a rule that would allow the compiler to prove it. The compiler cannot generally prove every provable property of your code.

To explain this case more specifically, your first example works in Typescript 4.4+ because of a new feature, referred to as [*Control Flow Analysis of Aliased Conditions and Discriminants*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) in the change notes. Essentially, the compiler has a specific rule which applies in your first example because in every execution path, the type guard's result is assigned directly to the variable `isKind1`; but the rule does not apply in your second example, because the value assigned to `isKind1` is the literal value `true`, which is not a type guard.

Comment: In that article I found this: "TypeScript will hop through constants to understand what sorts of checks you’ve already performed.". Note that word "constants", perhaps I should underline it in my memory...

Comment: Thus In link2 the compiler is not able to map a connection between `isKind1` and the TypeGuard. And the only way as of now to narrow down the type is to directly assign typeguard results ?

Comment: I understand it this way - you can use some kind of indirect assignments, but you should  make them all constant (so you cannot change them later and lie).

Answer (score 1):

In the given context , if `isKind1 === true` then `msg` will not always be of `kind1` as `isKind1` is a `let` can be set to true outside of the given `if` check.

Example

```js
const msg = {
  "foo": "bar"
}

let isKind1 = false
if (
    hasAllProperties<kind1>(msg, [
        "propertyA",
    ])
) {
    console.log("Kind1")
    isKind1 = true
}
// Assume if check didnt pass, thus isKind1 = false and msg is not of kind1

// Changing isKind1 externally
isKind1 = true

if (isKind1) {
    // Now even if isKind1 === true but msg will not be of type kind1
    console.log(msg.propertyA)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain it, because Typescript's control flow analysis will know whether you reassigned `isKind1` or not.

Comment: This answer was my conclusion on the given scenario. Even tho I agree Typescript's control flow analysis will know whether you reassigned the variable but that is either not working as expected in my case or the problem lies elsewhere.
Anyhow I am willing to accept any answer that could explain better.

Comment: I believe it may explain it, because Typescript's control flow analysis will have no idea if I reassign `isKind1` to for example to return value of some function. I suppose that anything else than `const` is "externaly changeable", so the value can't be paired to type guard. More here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: I find what @TomHANAX mentioned to be in stark contrast of @kaya3 comment  ,
 Typescript's control flow analysis will know whether you reassigned `isKind1`
Typescript's control flow analysis will have no idea if I reassign `isKind1`

Comment: Yes, I used wrong words. Of course Typescript will know "if" I reassign something, it just may have no idea to "what value". So you can't use `let`, you have to use `const`. My interpretation of how the "new feature" works.